# Clearing one radiobutton category when another category is clicked

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Im new with python gui and i follow a tutorial from a book and try to apply it to my work

im creating a little form, where you check the correct answers.

In my current problem i have 2 different possibilities. You can select analog or digital outputs.

However you cant choose both. so basically i want to "clear" the Analog Inputs with the defined variables, when im clicking on either rate or Link

Later i want to have a list depending on what you selected.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

top = tk.Tk()
top.title("Informations")
top.resizable(True, True)


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Analog Input ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
InputFrame=tk.LabelFrame(top,text="Analog Input",fg="blue")
InputFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, pady = 5, sticky=tk.N)

def InputCall():
    InputSel=InputVar.get()
    if      InputSel == 1: Input = 1
    elif    InputSel == 2: Input = 2

InputVar = tk.IntVar()

radInput1 = tk.Radiobutton(InputFrame, text="1", variable = InputVar, value=1, command=InputCall)
radInput1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

radInput2 = tk.Radiobutton(InputFrame, text="2", variable = InputVar, value=2, command=InputCall)
radInput2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Digital Input ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
DigitalInputFrame = tk.LabelFrame(top, text="Digital Input", fg="blue")
DigitalInputFrame.grid(column=1,row=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="N")

RateFrame= tk.LabelFrame(DigitalInputFrame, text="Rate", fg="blue")
RateFrame.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky= tk.N)

def RateCall():
    RateSel=RateVar.get()
    if      RateSel == 1: Rate = 1 
    elif    RateSel == 2: Rate = 2

RateVar  = tk.IntVar()
radRate1 = tk.Radiobutton(RateFrame, text="1", variable = RateVar, value = 1, command=RateCall)
radRate1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)
radRate1 = tk.Radiobutton(RateFrame, text="2", variable = RateVar, value = 2, command=RateCall)
radRate1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

LinkFrame= tk.LabelFrame(DigitalInputFrame, text="Link", fg="blue")
LinkFrame.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky="n")

def LinkCall():
    LinkSel=LinkVar.get()
    if      LinkSel == 1: Link = 1 
    elif    LinkSel == 2: Link = 2
    elif    LinkSel == 3: Link = 3
    elif    LinkSel == 4: Link = 4

LinkVar  = tk.IntVar()
radLink1 = tk.Radiobutton(LinkFrame, text="Link 1", variable = LinkVar, value=1, command=LinkCall)
radLink1.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

radLink2 = tk.Radiobutton(LinkFrame, text="Link 2", variable = LinkVar, value=2, command=LinkCall)
radLink2.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.W)

radLink3 = tk.Radiobutton(LinkFrame, text="Link 3", variable = LinkVar, value=3, command=LinkCall)
radLink3.grid(column=3, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

radLink4 = tk.Radiobutton(LinkFrame, text="Link 4", variable = LinkVar, value=4, command=LinkCall)
radLink4.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=tk.W)

# Display Form
top.mainloop()
```

[When you press on Analog 1, both rate and link should reset. Vice Versa.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOGS7.png)
Sincerely Pascal

I googled and found the .set or .reset function, but if im correct, it only deletes the black dot inside the radiobutton and doesnt reset the variable you made

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a smaller example? There seems to be a lot of unnecessary code in the example. There are over 20 radiobuttons in the example, but it seems like this problem could be illustrated with as few as six.

Comment: @BryanOakley i reduced so its really only the part that has my problem. i didnt want to remove the labelframes, since the grid is made based on thes frames. hope its now a lot better to read

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the associated variables to some value other than the ones that the user can set. For example, by setting them to zero.

```
def InputCall():
    InputSel=InputVar.get()
    if      InputSel == 1: Input = 1
    elif    InputSel == 2: Input = 2

    # reset the rate and link
    RateVar.set(0)
    LinkVar.set(0)
```

In this case zero is appropriate since that's the default value of an `IntVar`, so it becomes the value it was before the user set it.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to reset. The `Radiobutton` doesn't need `if/else` condition.

```
def InputCall():    
    RateVar.set(0)
    LinkVar.set(0)
```